# How to use the data from a list of a class?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm working on a quiz game using windows form application.
So what I'm confused on is how to assign the data I read from Trivia.cs (from the ListOfData method) to the variables (questionText) and (answers) in TriviaForm, so that it can be passed to the Question.cs to process the data and to figure out which one is the right answer.

I'm just a beginner and this is my high school introductory class so I'd really appreciate the help.

So I made a Trivia class (Trivia.cs) to read the data.

```
namespace D4
{
    class Trivia
    {
        // Fields
        private const string FileName = "WumpusTrivia.txt";
        private string questionText;
        private string[] answers = new string[4];

        public Trivia()
        {

        }

        /// This method will return the list of data.
        public List<Question> ListOfData()
        {
            List<Question> ls = new List<Question>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    this.questionText = sr.ReadLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        this.answers[i] = sr.ReadLine();
                    sr.ReadLine();
                    ls.Add(new Question(this.questionText, this.answers)); 
                }
            }
            return ls;
        }
    }
}
```

A Question class (Question.cs) to process the data and to return the values to put into text boxes.

```
namespace D4
{
    class Question
    {
        private string question;
        private string[] answers = new string[4];
        private int correctAnswer;
        private string[] freeTrivia;
        private Trivia trivia;

        public Question(string question, string[] answers)
        {
            this.trivia = new Trivia();

            this.question = question;
            this.answers = answers;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (answers[i].ToString().EndsWith("+"))
                {
                    this.correctAnswer = i;
                    answers[i].ToString().Replace('+', ' ');
                }
            }
        }

        public string QuestionText { get { return this.question; } }
        public string[] Answers { get { return this.answers; } }
        public int CorrectAnswer { get { return this.correctAnswer; } }
        public string[] Freetrivia { get { return this.freeTrivia; } }
    }
}
```

And a TriviaForm class (TriviaForm.cs) to display the data from the Trivia class in the textboxes.

```
namespace D4
{
    public partial class TriviaForm : Form
    {
        //// Fields
        private Trivia trivia;
        private Question question;
        private string questionText;
        private string[] answers = new string[4];
        private Question[] data;
        private const int wumpusMaxQuestions = 5;
        private const int hazardAndPurchaseMaxQuestions = 3;


        // Replace these later after finished connecting all objects.
        private bool hazardAndPurchase = false;
        private bool wumpus = false;

        public TriviaForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.trivia = new Trivia();
            this.data = trivia.ListOfData().ToArray();
            this.questionText = data[0].ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                this.answers[i] = data[i].ToString();

            this.question = new Question(questionText, answers);

            QuestionOutputter();
        }

        // Displays the questions and answers on the form.
        private void QuestionOutputter()
        {
            this.txtQuestion.Text = question.QuestionText;
            this.txtBoxA.Text = question.Answers[0];
            this.txtBoxB.Text = question.Answers[1];
            this.txtBoxC.Text = question.Answers[2];
            this.txtBoxD.Text = question.Answers[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Okay sorry for the bad question guys, but I finally figured it out. The problem I was having was with the Question class giving an error. This was due to the fact that I was passing a null to it with my questionText and answers variables in the TriviaForm class.
The code that I had:

```
this.data = trivia.ListOfData().ToArray();
        this.questionText = data[0].ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            this.answers[i] = data[i].ToString();
```

was completely wrong. Apparently all I needed was to do a foreach loop instead.
My solution:

```
this.data = trivia.ListOfData().ToArray();
foreach (Question q in this.data)
        {
            this.questionText = q.QuestionText.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                this.answers[i] = q.Answers[i];
            this.question = new Question(questionText, answers);
        }
```

I tried this out and it worked out really well! Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Please provide the least amount of code that shows your problem.

Comment: I'm missing the question here. This code looks like a really good start (and it looks like it would work on first glance). What isn't working? What is your question?

Comment: So what I'm confused on is how to assign the data I read from Trivia.cs (from the ListOfData method) to the variables (questionText) and (answers) in TriviaForm, so that it can be passed to the Question.cs to process the data and to figure out which one is the right answer.

Comment: I read that the first time, but it seems like the code you have *already does that*. Is something specific not working? Does some of the code confuse you? I don't see where the problem lies, but would love to help!

Answer (score 2):

Add a radio button next to each of the answer text boxes and add event handlers to those radio buttons to evaluate whether the selected answer is the correct one.

---

Something like this may work with your existing code, assuming you put radioButton2 next to txtBoxB, and radioButton3 next to txtBoxC etc:

```
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton)sender).Text.Substring(11,1) = this.Question.correctAnswer + 1) {
            CorrectAnswer_DoSomethingHere();
        } else {
            Incorrect_DoSomethingElse();   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even if this answers the question (which I don't know for sure, since I have no idea what he is actually asking), this answer doesn't say or explain anything. Radio buttons are a good choice for a "Trivia" application, but I fail to see how this is relevant.

Comment: The key is he needs to use event handlers to "process the data and figure out the correct answer".

Comment: I can see what you are saying (would still like some more info from the OP though). If you could expound on that, perhaps provide a sample handler or some background on C# events (since this person is clearly new) that would make it a much better answer.

Comment: Bradley has merit.  Some code to explain what you're talking about would be nice.